# My simple javascript codeeditor have some errors

Tags: javascript, html, editor

I have created a simple code editor but i dont know there is something error inside that. The HTML code i have used is

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<style>
textarea{
width: 33%;
height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="html" width="33%" oninput="validate()"></textarea>
<textarea id="css" width="33%" oninput="validate()"></textarea>
<textarea id="js" width="33%" oninput="validate()"></textarea>
<button onclick="validate()">Compile</button>
<div id="result" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The main.js script is given below:

```
function validate(){
//get the code values
var html1 = document.getElementById("html").value;
var css1 = document.getElementById("css").value;
var js1 = document.getElementById("js").value;

//Generate the code
var htmltag = "<body>"+ html1 + "</body>";
var csstag = "<style>" + css1 + "</style>";
var jstag = "<script>" + js1 + "</" + "script>";

var totalcode = "<html>" + "<head>"+ csstag + jstag + "</head>" + htmltag + "</html>";

//apply the code
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = totalcode;

}
```

no idea but there must be any mistake. and i am new to javascript so i don't have enoufgh knowledge about it :)
Thanx for the help in advanced.

Comment: Please either *use* jQuery to give you smaller simpler code, or *do not tag your question with jQuery* :)

Comment: oops mistakenly put that tag! really sorry! @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: Actually the bigger mistake is *not* using jQuery (to write shorter simpler code) :)

Comment: Please note it is invalid to try and put a second `HTML` and `HEAD` tag into an element within the page.

Comment: thanks.. Let me see if it works when i remove the secondary html and head tags.. @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie
I tried doing that but it still wont work..

Comment: I did not mean it was the whole solution, just that that was very wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems.

- You are trying to inject `HTML` and `HEAD` tags into a `DIV` which is invalid on a page.
- You are executing the script *before the HTML is present*, so move the jstag to the end.
- You really should only try and execute it all on pressing a run button (like JSFiddle does).

As you originally tagged this with jQuery (a good thing) I have written my version in jQuery:

```
$('#validate').click(function() {

    //get the code values
    var html1 = $("#html").text();
    var css1 = $("#css").text();
    var js1 = $("#js").text();

    //Generate the code
    var htmltag = html1;
    var csstag = "<style>" + css1 + "</style>";
    var jstag = "<script>" + js1 + "</" + "script>";

    var totalcode = csstag + htmltag + jstag;

    //apply the code
    $('#result').html(totalcode);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/jc48khkp/6/

I primed the `textarea`s with sample code, HTML and css for testing.

Feel free to lengthen it back to raw JavaScript if you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want execute the JS inside the textarea.

You don't need to encapsulate inside a script tag, since it's not a new request and then a new execution.

You should only call [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) on the content of js textarea.

```
function validate(){
    //get the code values
    var html1 = document.getElementById("html").value;
    var css1 = document.getElementById("css").value;
    var js1 = document.getElementById("js").value;

    //Generate the code
    var htmltag = "<body>"+ html1 + "</body>";
    var csstag = "<style>" + css1 + "</style>";
    var jstag = "<script>" + js1 + "</" + "script>";

    var totalcode = "<html>" + "<head>"+ csstag + jstag + "</head>" + htmltag + "</html>";
    eval(js1);
    //apply the code
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = totalcode;
}
```

Try with an simple alert.

Just be careful, that everytime that you type something, it will execute the code, this will cause a lot of errors on console, since the code isn't finished, try to remove this oninput and let only the button to execute validate function.

Comment: Hello, @mariodiniz
The javascript section is not working actually javascript may need to work in the whole document.. but i don't think thus i am making any mistake or what..
Even this javascript also don't perfrom the window.alert() or such functions :(

Comment: This would never work reliably as you are still calling the JavaScript code *before* the DOM elements are present.